# Glass.Mapper.MapperException: Failed to create type - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: youtube, sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

Following an earlier post, I'm implementing [this YouTube Video Picker](http://jockstothecore.com/youtube-video-picker-part-1-introduction/) in Sitecore - this has involved creating a custom Field Type (YouTubeVideoField). the control itself works no problem but when trying to get the video on the page (*@Html.Sitecore().Field("YouTube Video")*) I get the following error. Any ideas?

> 

```
5824 15:50:34 ERROR Unhandled exception occurred
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Layouts/_Default.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Component/YouTubeVideo.cshtml'.

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Layouts__Default_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\Views\Layouts\_Default.cshtml:line 27
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException
Message: Failed to create type BrainJocks.YouTube.Custom.FieldTypes.YouTubeVideoField
Source: Glass.Mapper
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 117
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 68
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreateTaskExpression>b__2(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 77
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreateTaskExpression>b__2(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 82
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreateTaskExpression>b__2(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 82
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreateTaskExpression>b__2(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 82
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreateTaskExpression>b__2(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 82
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreateTaskExpression>b__2(T args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\AbstractPipelineRunner.cs:line 82
   at Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:line 138
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.CreateType(Type type, Item item, Boolean isLazy, Boolean inferType, Dictionary`2 parameters, Object[] constructorParameters) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:line 495
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetObject(String model, Database db, Rendering renderingItem) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc\Pipelines\Response\GetModel.cs:line 240
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetObject(String model, Database db, Rendering renderingItem) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc\Pipelines\Response\GetModel.cs:line 188
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.Process(GetModelArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc\Pipelines\Response\GetModel.cs:line 92
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateConcrete\CreateConcreteTask.cs:line 100
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Dan

EDIT: So I'm reading through the [Glass Mapper tutorials](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial19) - do i need to create a custom data handler?

Comment: Does `YouTubeVideoField` type has parameteless constructor?

Comment: no @MarekMusielak - it inherits from Sitecore.Data.Fields.CustomField and does not allow parameter less constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to implement a custom data handler. If you want to use the supplied custom field see these examples:

https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/DataMappers/SitecoreFieldScWrapperMappers.cs